# Reading a file with special characters in Batch

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, io, special-characters

How do I read and parse a file with special characters in Batch? I have a text file named test.txt with just `foo!!!bar` and a batch file with this:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion enableextensions

FOR /F "tokens=* delims=" %%a IN (.\test.txt) DO (
    echo Unquoted is %%a
    echo Quoted is "%%a"
    set "myVar=%%a"
    echo myVar is still !myVar! or "!myVar!"
)
exit /b 0
```

I want and expect it to output `foo!!!bar` somehow, but this outputs:

```
Unquoted is foobar
Quoted is "foobar"
myVar is still foobar or "foobar"
```

Of course I can just `type test.txt`, but I want to process each line of the file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is a side effect of the batch parser and it's phases.

The FOR parameters are expanded just before the delayed expansion phase would be expand.
But when `%%a` is `foo!!bar`, then the delayed expansion would remove the exclamation marks, as `!!` isn't a valid variable expansion.

You need to toggle the delayed expansion, as expanding of `%%a` is only safe with disabled delayed expansion.

```
@echo off
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion enableextensions

FOR /F "tokens=* delims=" %%a IN (.\test.txt) DO (
    echo Unquoted is %%a
    echo Quoted is "%%a"
    set "myVar=%%a"

    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion 
    echo myVar is still !myVar! or "!myVar!"
    endlocal
)
```

You could also look at [How does the CMD.EXE parse...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094699/how-does-the-windows-command-interpreter-cmd-exe-parse-scripts/4095133#4095133)

Comment: In my case I used same toggle before I write the content into file, but getting error please help me