# While splitting txt file through batch script Exclamations are ommitting

Tags: batch-file, cmd, windows-scripting, batching, filesplitting

Iam new to batch script and here I tried to split my text file into chunks for each 1 million rows.
Chunk files are generated as I expected, but inside the output file content Iam missing the Exclamations ( ! ) and even it skipping the immediate column after Exclamation. Please help me to get data as it is in original file into chunks!

```
@ECHO OFF
setLocal DisableDelayedExpansion

set limit=1000000
set feed_name=test.txt
set file=%Tgt_Dir%\%feed_name%
set lineCounter=1
set filenameCounter=1
set name=
set extension=


for %%a in (%file%) do (
    set "name=%%~na"
    set "extension=%%~xa"
)

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (%file%) do (
    set splitFile=!name!%date:~12,2%%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%!filenameCounter!!extension!
    if !lineCounter! gtr !limit! (
        set /a filenameCounter=!filenameCounter! + 1
        set lineCounter=1
        echo Created !splitFile!.
    )
    echo %%a>> %Tgt_Dir%\!splitFile!

    set /a lineCounter=!lineCounter! + 1
)
endlocal
```

It is a Tab delimiter file.

**ScreenShot**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to toggle delayed expansion.

```
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion 
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (%file%) do (
    Set "line=%%a"
    setlocal  EnableDelayedExpansion 

        set splitFile=!name!%date:~12,2%%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%!filenameCounter!!extension!

        echo(!line!>> %Tgt_Dir%\!splitFile!

    if !lineCounter! gtr !limit! (
        ENDLOCAL
        set /a filenameCounter+=1
        set lineCounter=1
        echo Created file
    ) ELSE ENDLOCAL
    set /a lineCounter=lineCounter + 1
)
```

Comment: Really thanks for your suggestion, even I read ur another thread too on this issue.  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10964923/reading-a-file-with-special-characters-in-batch)
But even after your suggested changes above, I still getting error - Now chucks are creating for each line and content showing **%A**

Comment: @CIPHER I wrote `%%A` instead `%%a`, now I fixed it. And also a bug in the line`if !lineCounter! gtr !limit! ` there must be delayed expansion be still enabled, therefore I moved the endlocal just after the compare, and also into the ELSE part

Comment: Thanks jeb, I initially identified issue in accessing %%A, but later with your other modifications I can able to get results.